# How to get MD5 hash of a file before you save the file to Mongo Db using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

How to get MD5 hash of a file being downloaded from the server before you save the file to Mongo Db using Node JS ?. Because I am download a file from a remote server and then I directly pipe the request stream to the gridfs write stream and now it is stored on the mongo db with its MD5 data and etc. Now I want to avoid saving duplicates so that it will only save files which does not exist.

Now , How to get MD5 hash of a file being downloaded so that i can compare the md5 hash to the once stored in the databse. Cause on my example I just directly pipe the request stream to the gridfs write stream.

Any idea. thanyou.

## Sample Code

```
var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
var download = function (url, dest, filename callback) {

    const file = filename
     const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: file});

     request.get(url)
         .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
         .pipe(fileStorage)
         .on('close', callback);

 };

 final_list.forEach(function (str) {
     var filename = str.split('/').pop();

     console.log('Downloading ' + filename);

     download(str, filename, function () { console.log('Finished Downloading' + "" + filename) });
 });
```

Comment: Please don't re-post questions. You have posted this same question 4 times as far as I can see, back to the original comment from me on the original question. **You cannot obtain an MD5 from a stream**.  You can do one **only** when the complete content of the file is loaded or stored locally a a disk or otherwise once all bytes of the file have been processed. This can only happen **after** and **not before**.

Comment: So any idea on how we can avoid storing dups in mongo grid fs ?

Comment: Beyond what you have already been told? **No**. If you want an MD5 you **must load the complete file**. This **cannot be done with `pipe()`**. Please add to your original question if you really must. You cannot keep posting the same question.

Comment: So you mean i need to download the file to the disk first ?

Comment: doesn't have to be to disk

Comment: @Bravo , so what it is ?

Comment: I'm sorry I got involved in season 4 of this question - all you need to know was revealed in the season finale of season 1

Comment: lol @Bravo , xd ..

Comment: not sure of file sizes you are dealing with, but it's fairly simple to store the content of a request in a variable if need be

Comment: just around 5mb for each file

Comment: how about creating an index on the automatically generated md5 field of your GridFS storage. That way it would reject duplicates automatically.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200489/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-bravo).

Comment: Did you just make a suggestion to yourself as if you were making a suggestion to someone else?

Comment: i have already loaded the complete file , now how will i get the md5?

Comment: what do you mean by loading the complete file

Comment: ? so that i could get the md5?

Comment: I'm just looking at the question -- it is marked as duplicate but the original source doesn't exist. Could someone give me a link please?